# Create a component with attributes to bind data

Tags: angular, angular-cli, web-component

I'm using the current version of `Angular CLI/4` and I have a piece of code (HTML + actual JS code) which occurrs in multiple parts in my app. I think it would be great to just create a component and add that wherever I need it, but I need to feed in some data I get from a server and I need to get some data out of the component as well.
I understand how to create components and how to use them, but I couldn't find a way to create a custom attribute for it, via which I can 2-way bind an object to it.
So what I want is the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  template: '<app-myComponent [(data)]="myDataList" [(selector)]="selection"></app-myComponent>'
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  myDataList: any;
  selection: string;

  // And then constructor and init method with the call to the server, which will set the myDataList and so on.
}
```

So in my example, the component would display the stuff in `data`, which it get's via `myDataList` and if something is selected it would set the variable `selection`, which is provided via `selector`.

I have found `Directives`, `Annotations` and `Decorators`, but I'm not sure that this is what I want.

I really need your help here.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would suggest going through the Angular tutorial on angular.io https://angular.io/tutorial then there is a specific guide on Component Interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Thank you so very much! I've looked through that and must have skipped that part like 10 times.

Comment: In addition to that, you can take a look at the following plnkr to understand how to pass data between sibling components. https://plnkr.co/edit/tcMOMnHIdADk73FYo3Z1?p=info

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup an angular service that will be a dataprovider for each component you are using.

you inject the service in each component.
read this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7xPwhwbcHE